# Changing size of breakpoint column in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning how to use android studio, and I'm enjoying it so far. However, I'm a little bit OCD, and the breakpoint column in my version of Android Studio is really wide and it's kind of annoying me. I can't figure out how to resize it! I first provided a screenshot of the instructor's Android Studio, followed by mine: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJBAF.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to change the size of the gutter.

From what I am able to see in the tiny portion of the screenshots, the difference between your gutter, and the instructor's, might be due to original screen resolution or Android Studio's version.

That said, there is one very simple way to indirectly change the size of the gutter by disabling the icons shown on it.

On Android Studio go to Preferences > Editor > General > Gutter Icons, and uncheck *Show gutter icons*. It will reduce the gutter size to something similar to what can be seen in the instructor's screenshot (although, he does have gutter icons).

[image]